# Issue with Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

That might be a very simple problem, but I don't seem to understand why it doesn't work. 
I have a `LaTeX` document for which I want to add a bibliography.

I have a document called `Bibli.bib` which is like this

```
 @article{Reference1,
Author = {Chris Cavette \& David N. Ford},
Title = {How Printed Circuit Boards Are Made.},
url = {http://www.madehow.com/Volume-2/Printed-Circuit-Board.html}
Year = {Last accessed on 03/02/2016}}
```

in my main document, I have a paragraph, after which I put `\cite{Reference1}`.

I use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` because I want to display the URL (and it doesn't work with plain).

But instead of getting number for references `[1]`, I get `[Ford()]`.

I don't understand cause it's the first time that happens to me.

I don't use the `natbib` package here, but if I do and change the style to `unsrtnat`, then in the reference page I lose the `[Ford()]`, and in the text itself, it stays `Ford`, instead of `[1]`. 
Cheers

EDIT: It's hard ot put a runable example but here's the part of my code:

```
\begin document
couche étant séparée par une couche isolante. De cette facon, il est possible de connecter les composants à la surface directement à une certaine couche en percant des trous d'une profondeur spécifique\cite{Reference1}.
    \newpage

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{Bibli.bib}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable example, not just a `.bib` file

Comment: I added some part of code you can use

Comment: Can you check, if there is a comma missing after the url?

Comment: At one point, you state that you use the bibliography style `unsrtnat`, but later on you state it is `unsrt`. Please advise which style you use.

Comment: The `unsrt` *and* `plain` bibliography styles do not recognize a field named `url`, and hence don't process its contents. If you want to have entries with fields named `url`, you should use `plainnat` or `unsrtnat`. The styles generate identically formatted entries; their only difference is that the latter doesn't sort the entries alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style and generate numeric-style citation call-outs, be sure to also load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers` in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Three additional, separate issues:

- You're missing a comma at the end of the `url` field.
- The keyword to be used to separate authors is `and`, not `\&`. Thus, please write the author field as follows:

  ```
  Author = {Chris Cavette and David N. Ford},
  ```
- Don't use the `@article` entry type unless the piece is published in a journal. For the entry at hand, `@misc` would seem to be more appropriate.